# How to use custom directives.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have mentioned HTML code below

```
<div class="panel" ng-controller="myController">
   <div  myArr="arr" my-Dir="">
</div>
```

JavaScript is

```
app.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
// here i have one array of objects arr is here
}])
```

and Directive is

```
app.directive("myDir", function() {
scope: {
     myArr: "=",
    },
    templateUrl: "views/myHTML.html"
  };
});
```

Here I am including myHTML.html file. How do I pass the array to this file?. I need this array in myHTML.html file. I want to display the array elements in the myHTML using the `ng-repeat.`

Comment: use your directive in HTML in snake-case... ie my-arr="" instead of myArr="".

Comment: checked it didn't worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using dayArr in the html and then trying to isolate your scope on something called dayArray. These don't match up. You also need to pass the array into dayArr so that it can actually have a value in your scope

I've updated the fiddle to have a working example http://jsfiddle.net/zpWsz/2/

This is the relevant bits:

Here is where I pass in some dummy array.

```
<div  my-dir="" day-arr="[1,2,3]" >
```

Here is the updated directive pieces:

```
    scope: {
      dayArr : "="
    },
    template: '<ul>' + 
              '<li ng-repeat="i in dayArr">{{ i }}</li>' +
              '</ul>',
```

A templateUrl would work too, but how you had it in the fiddle was throwing js errors.

Hope this helped.

Comment: excellent! I was trying to figure out template url issue you beat me to it

Comment: hello how we can provide the click event to the '<li ng-repeat="i in dayArr">{{ i }}</li>

Comment: You can refer to the documentation for these things. Please see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch.directive:ngClick

Answer (score 0):

custom directive template

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
          myArr: "=",
        },
        restrict: 'EAC',
        templateUrl: 'views/myHTML.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) { }
    };
});
```

And to use it

```
<div data-my-dir data-my-arr="arr">
```

Comment: create a fiddle and post it here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shardulpendse/zpWsz/1/

I have added the fiddle. 
Please let me know asap